# how to trigger beforeUnmount() of a component inside a nested Vue3 instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-component, vuejs3

Hi so i will get straight to the point, i am having a Vue example with two different route **"/"** and **"/view2"**. And in **/view2** i am trying to create another Vue instance with "createApp" and mount it to a HTML element, but when i switch to a different route, the components inside of the nested app does not trigger beforeUnmount(). For a better illustration, here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-ganguly-3wejhv) i built on codesandbox.io. But for a quick summary, i will be showing my code below. So for the first route, i have a component like this
( View1.vue )

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>View 1</h1>
    <button @click="redirect">Go to view 2</button>
    <Test />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    redirect() {
      this.$router.push({ path: "/view2" });
    },
  },
  beforeUnmount() {
    console.log("Unmounting view 1");
  },
};
</script>
```

And for **/view2** i have a component like this ( View2.vue )

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>View 2</h1>
    <button @click="redirect">Go to view 1</button>

    <div id="extra_container"></div>
  </div>
</template>


<style scoped>
#extra_container {
  background-color: wheat;
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<script>
import ExtraComp from "./ExtraComp.vue";
import TestComponent from "./TestComponent.vue";
import { createApp } from "vue";

export default {
  mounted() {
    createApp(ExtraComp)
      .component("Test", TestComponent)
      .mount("#extra_container");
  },
  methods: {
    redirect() {
      this.$router.push({ path: "/" });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see i am trying to create another instance or app from the ExtraComp.vue component, so here it is

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <label>Extra app here</label>
    <Test />
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  beforeUnmount() {
    console.log("Unmounting extra component");
  },
};
</script>
```

About the TestComponent.vue, it is just a global component which i want every other view or nested apps to have access to, so here it is

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <label>Testing component</label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Test",
  beforeUnmount() {
    console.log("Unmounting...");
  },
};
</script>


<style scoped>
div {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

The problem is whenever i switch from View1 to View2, beforeUnmount seem to trigger in the <Test /> component but when i switch from View2 to View1, it does not trigger. So is there anyhow i can make the beforeUnmount() of the <Test /> component inside the nested app happen without getting rid of the nested instance ?